# Subscript Out Of Range when parsing array items in VBA dictionary - index 0 cannot be used

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, indexing

I created a text file with 1 line which looked like this `{"key 1":["item1","item2"],"key 2":"ItemX"}` and saved it as test.json. I then tried parsing the items in the array in "key 1", using the VBA subroutine below:

```
Sub testjs3()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim JsonTS As TextStream
    Dim JsonText As String
    Dim Parsed As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.json", ForReading)
    JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close
    Debug.Print JsonText
    Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)
    
    Debug.Print Parsed.Item("key 1")(0)
    Debug.Print Parsed.Item("key 1")(1)

End Sub
```

The line `Debug.Print Parsed.Item("key 1")(0)` caused VBA to return Subscript Out Of Range error, whereas if I commented out that faulty line, the next line that parsed "key 1" for item at index 1 seemed to return the first item in the array which in this case was "item1". I can't figured out why index 0 was returning error.

I then used another subroutine that created the dictionary instead of reading it from a json file, the subroutine is as below:

```
Sub test4()
 Dim keywords As Object
    
    Set keywords = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    keywords.Add "key 1", Array("item1", "item2")
    keywords.Add "key 2", "ItemX"
    
    Debug.Print keywords.Item("key 1")(0)
    Debug.Print keywords.Item("key 1")(1)
    Debug.Print keywords.Item("key 2")
    
    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(keywords)
        
End Sub
```

This time the dictionary returned the correct item in the array of "key 1" using index 0, and the debug print also showed both json strings read from the file and the one created via dictionary .add command were identical.

I am sure I missed something, your advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: `Parsed.Item("key 1")` returns a `Collection` and as is often the case with such it has a start index of `1` so the first element is `keywords.Item("key 1")(1)` not  `(0)`

Comment: Hi Alex, then how about the code in subroutine test4(), it used the same command and access method, but index 0 points to the first item. What's the difference that caused the behavior such way ?

Comment: Make the last line of you 2 subs `Debug.Print TypeName(keywords.Item("key 1"))` and you will see the difference - one is a 1-based Collection, the other a 0-based array.

Comment: Hi Alex, you are absolutely correct (and Thanks !). Following your suggestion did show the difference in the array types of 2 dictionaries. I used the VBE Watch window, it showed the same thing as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Alex has the answer. The array returned in `JsonConverter.ParseJson` is of type Collection which starts from index 1, whereas the array created via dictionary object `.add` method is of type 0-based array which starts from index 0.
[image]